# How to make iOS FBSDKProfilePictureView Round?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I'm trying to making a FBSDKProfilePictureView rounded but I can't.

This what I have:

ViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKProfilePictureView *fbPhoto;
```

ViewController.m on ViewDidLoad

```
self.fbPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0;
self.fbPhoto.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
self.fbPhoto.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

It makes a round circle in front of the UIIMage but it doesn't "crop" the image.

How can i do it

Comment: try this self.fbPhoto.layer.clipToBounds = YES; or self.fbPhoto.layer.maskToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just set `clipsToBounds`

```
self.fbPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0;
self.fbPhoto.clipsToBounds=YES;
self.fbPhoto.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
self.fbPhoto.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all for set rounded profile picture like whats up and FB, you can use below logic for that and after set `setAutoresizesSubviews` to `NO` of fbPhoto class.

use below code instead of your..

```
[self.fbPhoto.layer setCornerRadius:self.fbPhoto.frame.size.height/2];
[self.fbPhoto.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[self. fbPhoto.layer setBorderWidth:1];
[self.fbPhoto setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Jay's suggestion works. Here it is in swift:

```
    //rounded corners
    ProfilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = ProfilePicture.frame.size.width / 2
    ProfilePicture.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    ProfilePicture.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    ProfilePicture.clipsToBounds = true
```